# Call Controller action from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I Have Controller action in my Bank Controller ("BankController") name Add that illustrate below  :

```
public ActionResult Add()
{
    return View();
}
```

Now How can i call my action from java script.
Note : My action return type is "ActionResult"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an AJAX call:

```
<div id='some-container'>Loading...</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get('@Url.Action("Add", "BankController")', function(viewResult) {
            $("#some-container").html(viewResult);
            alert(viewResult);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Mr. dbaseman & Mohit Arora My view is a partial view I want to display my view as partial

Comment: @MohammedFaruk in that case, use the JQuery `html` function to place it in your target.  See my updated answer.

Comment: if it is  @RenderBody()   then?

Comment: basically i manipulate a tree for menu & I try to when i click tree label display my view in my  @RenderBody()

Comment: @MohammedFaruk in my example, you could wrap `RenderBody` with the div.  `<div id='some-container'>@RenderBody()</div>`